# Transaction reverted during simulation for create an open book market on raydium

Tags: phantom, raydium

i try to create an open book market on raydium and when i what to pay the fees i get this  "Transaction reverted during simulation".
thanks for the answer

Comment: We're going to need more information than that, otherwise this question will be closed for lack of context

Comment: i create a token and when i try to create the open market book with raydium and my phantom wallet i get Transaction reverted during simulation then if i to validate the transaction i get this error on solscan  FailFinalized (MAX confirmations) Program Error: "Instruction #5 Failed'

Comment: Please provide code samples of the script or CLI commands you are trying to run when you encounter this error, and add things like what network you're using (mainnet or devnet), what token pairs you are using for the market (mint addresses are best) and confirm basic facts like if you have SOL in that wallet, if you are using custom instructions or the basic commands in the documentation, etc.

Without giving more information, it's tough to identify where the transaction is failing. The "Instruction #5 failed" error is only useful when we know the program and version you are interacting with